# Pandas interprets 'timestamp without timezones' columns as different types

Tags: pandas

I read a table with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
con = psycopg2.connect(...)
mframe = pd.read_sql('''select dt_A, dt_B from (...)''',con)
```

Both columns (dt_A and dt_B) are of type 'timestamp without timezone' in the database. However, they are read as different types by pandas:

```
mframe.dt_A.dtype,  mframe.dt_B.dtype
```

Yields:

```
(dtype('O'), dtype('<M8[ns]'))
```

I was able to force both columns to be recognized as

```
"<M8[ns]"
```

using the 'parse_dates' parameter, but I'd like to understand what causes this. As far as I've checked, neither column contains any 'Na's (which was my first suspicion). What could case them to be interpreted differently?

Update: 
I'm using Pandas version 0.15.1; and I can reproduce the problem using both `sqlalchemy` and `psycopg2` connections.

Update 2: running the original query with a small `limit` works as I expected - that is, both columns have the same dtype "M8[ns]". Still not sure what kind of entry (something ill-formatted?) is causing this, but I'm satisfied for now.

Update 3: joris got it. See the comments below.

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? Further, can you try the same using an `sqlalchemy` engine (instead of a `psycopg2` connection), see http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/engines.html#postgresql

Comment: @joris I'll update the question with what you asked. Thanks.

Comment: Can you limit the amount of data read in (eg with adding `LIMIT 5` to your query), to check if the reason lies in the data itself, or is caused by something else. Also, if possible, can you show some data of `mframe`?

Comment: Thanks, @joris, I ran the query with `limit` and indeed the type is now "<M8[ns]". Finding an entry that is causing this might be a problem, though, as the table has over 400k rows.

Comment: A possible way to find the entry, is to do `pd.to_datetime(column, errors='raise')` yourself on the column that is returned as object dtype. This will then error on the line that cannot be converted.

Comment: Great, I got it! The problem in this case was that a date was completely out of bounds (year 3800+) causing `OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp`. If you want to reply with an answer I'll accept it. Thanks again, @joris.

Comment: Added an answer. Still I find it strange that `read_sql` does not convert it automatically to NaT, so opened an issue for that: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9261

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted that it works correctly when limiting to some data (with adding `LIMIT 5` to your query), it probably has to do with some 'incorrect' values in the dates.
To find out what value is causing the problem, you can read in all data (resulting in the object dtype), and then do the conversion manually with:

```
pd.to_datetime(column, errors='raise')
```

The `errors='raise'` will ensure you get an error message indicating which date cannot be converted.

To ensure that the column is converted to datetime64 values, regardless of invalid values, you should specify the column in the `parse_dates` kwarg.

---

It seems that when using `read_sql_table`, the invalid date will be converted to `NaT` automatically, while `read_sql_query` will leave the values as `datetime.datetime` values. I opened an issue for this inconsistency: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9261