# Pandas Dataframe Inconsistently Pulling Back Oracle Datatypes?

Tags: python, oracle, pandas, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle

I am trying to use Pandas and SQLAlchemy to do some auto-profiling of data in an Oracle database. However, Pandas (or SQLAlchemy, or cx_Oracle, I am not sure which) seems to be inconsistently reading the datatypes which are defined in Oracle.

For example, here are some columns in the table (as defined in Oracle):

Column Name, Datatype

```
PRINCIPAL_PHOTOGRAPHY_END_DATE  DATE    
PRINCIPAL_PHOTO_START_DATE  DATE
PRODUCER    VARCHAR2(26 BYTE)
RELEASE_AIR_DATE    VARCHAR2(26 BYTE)
RUNNING_TIME_MINUTES    NUMBER(38,0)
RUNNING_TIME_SECONDS    NUMBER(38,0)
EFFECTIVE_TIMESTAMP DATE
EXPIRE_TIMESTAMP    DATE
```

And here is code that I use to connect and grab info from the table and load it into a pandas dataframe:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
import pandas as pd
orcl_connect_string = 'oracle+cx_oracle://system:oracle@192.168.56.101:1521/?service_name=orcl'
engine = create_engine(orcl_connect_string)
df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM INT_PROP', engine)
print df.dtypes
```

And what I get as output is very confusing because it is not consistent -- it catches the datetime data type in one case but not in others...!?

```
production_start_date                     object
principal_photography_end_date            object
producer                                  object
release_air_date                          object
running_time_minutes                     float64
running_time_seconds                     float64
effective_timestamp               datetime64[ns]
expire_timestamp                          object
```

Any ideas why Pandas seems to be able to read the appropriate datatype for the effective_timestamp column but not for the other columns?

EDIT (Some version info):

1. Oracle 12c
2. Python 2.7.6
3. SQLAlchemy 1.0.8
4. Pandas 0.16.2

Comment: are there some null values or non-date values in the other columns? that cannot be converted to datetime (I dont know how well oracle enforces types )

Comment: The other columns are nullable and do have some null entries in them. However, I don't see why that should be an issue -- Oracle does enforce the datatypes. Having a date column doesn't mean values can't be null in it -- it just means they can't be non-dates. "NULL" is a valid date, it's a valid number, etc. At least in all relational databases I have worked with. Does Pandas object to having null values in columns that are not of type "object"?

Comment: a column in pandas must all be the same type or you will get dtype object ... clearly None is a different type than datetime :P

Comment: I am a little confused after reviewing this part of the pandas documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html. It seems to indicate that pandas can actually handle this scenario with NaN and NaT. In other words, I would have expected a dataframe to come back with all of the NULL values in the database represented by NaN or NaT (as relevant for the particular datatype) but with the datatype properly categorized.

Comment: that's not an  unreasonable expectation however I really don't know enough about pandas to really be able to help you that's why I just posted a comment...

Comment: have you tried passing the date columns to the `parse_dates` parameter? E.g., `pd.read_sql_query('select * from int_prop', parse_dates=['principal_photography_start_date', ...])`. I've seen similar behaviour recently and that worked.

Comment: You might also want to try `read_sql_table('INT_PROP', engine)`. With this function, pandas uses the actual types in the database to try to correctly type the values in the dataframe (in `read_sql_query` it just receives values from the databases without knowing about the database schema)

Comment: I did try `read_sql_table('INT_PROP', engine)` but I get back this error message: `ValueError: Table INT_PROP not found`
This is despite the fact that `pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM INT_PROP')` works perfectly.

Comment: Oops, I meant that `pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM INT_PROP', engine)` works perfectly.

Comment: I had [a similar problem once with psycopg2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27908071/pandas-interprets-timestamp-without-timezones-columns-as-different-types) once. In my case, what happened was that somewhere along the values in the time-stamp column, as dates were converted to seconds, a date like 2038 was overflowing the number datatype.

Comment: While it's not related to my original reason for opening the question, I have just opened an issue on the pandas error log about the issue with read_sql_query() working but not read_sql_table() -- see here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11258

Answer (score 1):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Description: Autonomous Database Data uploader from different kind files
       Date: Oct 10, 2010
     Python: 3.7
   Packages: cx_Oracle, sqlalchemy, pandas, xlrd
"""
import cx_Oracle
import sqlalchemy
import pandas as pd
import os
import json 
import argparse
import re
import sys


def preCheck():
    """
    Check whether there is user configuration json files and client.
    """

    # Check the existence of TNS_ADMIN
    if os.environ.get('ORACLE_HOME') :
        if os.environ.get('TNS_ADMIN') :
            # Check the existence of the configuration file.
            if not os.path.exists("./.config.json") :
                configADB()
        else:
            print("""
First, download the Autonomous Database Wallet from OCI into the instant client directory.
Secondly, set the environment variable TNS_ADMIN.
Third, modify the sqlnet.ora to contain the correct wallet file path.
Finally, run this program!
                  """)
            exit(-1)
    else:
        print("""
First, download the instant client driver from:
   https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/downloads.html
Secondly, set the environment variable ORACLE_HOME.
Finally, run this program!
          """)
        exit(-1)

def configADB():
    """
    Configure the Autonomous Database Connection
    """
    cfg={}
    cfg['user']=input("Enter your ADB username:")
    cfg['passwd']=input("Enter your ADB user's password:")
    cfg['TNS']=input("Enter your ADB TNS's name:")

    cfgFile=open("./.config.json",'w')
    json.dump(cfg,cfgFile)
    cfgFile.close()

def adbConnect():
    """
    Establish the database connection
    """
    cfgFile=open("./.config.json",'r')
    cfg={}
    cfg=json.load(cfgFile)
    cfgFile.close()

    os.environ['NLS_LANG']="SIMPLIFIED CHINESE_CHINA.UTF8"
    connstr= "oracle+cx_oracle://{}:{}@{}".format(cfg['user'],cfg['passwd'],cfg['TNS'])
    return sqlalchemy.create_engine(connstr, max_identifier_length=128)

def loadCSV(conn, destSchema, destTable, dataType, srcFile):
    """
    Load csv data into ADB
    """
    df=pd.read_csv(srcFile,encoding='utf-8')
    df.to_sql(destTable, conn, schema=destSchema, if_exists='append', index=False, chunksize=10000, dtype=dataType)

def loadJSON(conn, destSchema, destTable, dataType, srcFile):
    """
    Load JSON data into ADB
    """
    df=pd.read_json(srcFile)
    df.to_sql(destTable, conn, schema=destSchema, if_exists='append', index=False, chunksize=10000, dtype=dataType)

def loadExcel(conn, destSchema, destTable, dataType, srcFile):
    """
    Load Excel data into ADB
    """
    df=pd.read_excel(srcFile)
    df.to_sql(destTable, conn, schema=destSchema, if_exists='append', index=False, chunksize=10000, dtype=dataType)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-s", "--schema", help="Autonomous Database's schema")
    parser.add_argument("-t", "--table", help="Schema's table")
    parser.add_argument("-d", "--srcFile", help="Source data file to been loaded")
    args = vars(parser.parse_args())

    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        parser.print_help()
        exit(-1)

    preCheck()
    adbConn=adbConnect()

    # Generate the dtype
    colType={}
    metadata=sqlalchemy.MetaData(schema=args['schema'])
    tabDef=sqlalchemy.Table(args['table'], metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=adbConn)
    for col in tabDef.columns:
        colType[col.name]=col.type

    if re.search("\.csv",args['srcFile']) :
        loadCSV(adbConn, args['schema'], args['table'], colType, args['srcFile'])

    if re.search("\.json",args['srcFile']) :
        loadJSON(adbConn, args['schema'], args['table'], colType, args['srcFile'])

    if re.search("\.(xls|xlsx)",args['srcFile']) :
        loadExcel(adbConn, args['schema'], args['table'], colType, args['srcFile'])

    # Close the connection    
    adbConn.dispose()
```